# Matlab: Financial time series plot xTickLable bug?

Tags: matlab, plot, time-series, matlab-figure

I think this might be a bug. I am using Matlab 2015a. After I created a fints (financial time series) object, when I tried to plot it, the xTickLabel would not update when I zoomed in. If I set the `xTickMode` to `Auto`, then it would mess up itself.

I did this. You can simply do the same and see what happens:

```
% Create financial time series:
url_1 = fred('https://research.stlouisfed.org/fred2/');
FredData = fetch(url_1, 'PERMIT');
dates = FredData.Data(:,1);
Data = FredData.Data(:,2);    
fts = fints(dates, Data , 'PERMIT');
close(url_1);

%% Plot
F1 = figure;
h1 = plot (fts.PERMIT);
```

Here if you zoom in, then the yTickLabel will update but not the xTickLabel.
If you type `get(gca, 'yTickMode')`, you will get `auto`. If you type `get(gca, 'xTickMode')`, you will get `manual`.

Now the problem comes. If you try to fix the lack of automatic update problem of the xTickLable, you will natually type `set(gca, 'xTickMode', 'auto')`. Afterwards, what you get is a messed up xTickLable.
It's not a hard-to-read problem that could be solved by rotation of the xTickLabel. The time itself will get messed up, so that you no longer know at which time the data were registered when you look at the chart. You can try it yourself, and then you will see what I mean.

My question is, how to fix this or bypass this problem.

Thanks!

Comment: This problem exists also in 2017a.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can workaround this by using the `plot` in with its common syntax and then set the x-tick-label format:

```
plot(datetime(datestr(dates)),Data)
xtickformat('dd-MMM-yyyy');
legend('PERMIT')
grid on
```

[image]